# Map Box Styles in QGIS

Tags: qgis, mapbox

I just changed the mountain peak label from the outdoors style (mapbox).
As the default there is just a mountain icon + the name of the mountain.
I also wanted to label the elevation but when I import the style to QGIS my style change is not getting displayed.

Here the label when I import the changed style to QGIS:[image]

Here the changes I made (displayed in the mapbox viewer) the label should look like this in QGIS: [image]

Comment: Could you share your data? Screenshot of attribute table will be enough.

Comment: 1. Did you publish your style?
2. It could be that either Mapbox or QGIS are still caching an older raster tile. You could just try again later.